# How to do a calculator with XML and XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I am building an expression calculator using **XSD**, **XML** and **XSLT**.

At the moment only `Sum` operation is implemented.

I have already developed the `xml-schema` and a valid `xml` document.

**SCHEMA (XSD)**

```
<xs:complexType name="typeSum">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="exp:Expression"/>
            <xs:element ref="exp:Expression"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="EE">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="exp:Expression" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="Expression" abstract="true"/>
<xs:element name="EE" type="exp:EE"/>
<xs:element name="Const" type="xs:integer" substitutionGroup="exp:Expression"/>
<xs:element name="Sum" type="exp:typeSum" substitutionGroup="exp:Expression"/>
```

**XML (In this XML I would like to do the following: `Sum(Sum(8,4),Sum(1,2))`)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<e:EE xmlns:e="expr"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="xxx/xxx/xxx...">
    <e:Sum>
       <e:Sum>
           <e:Const>
               8
           </e:Const>
           <e:Const>
               4
           </e:Const>
       </e:Sum>
        <e:Sum>
            <e:Const>
                1
            </e:Const>
            <e:Const>
                2
            </e:Const>
        </e:Sum>
    </e:Sum>
</e:EE>
```

The problem comes with the **XSLT**. This is what I have tried so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:e="expr"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output
        method="xml"
        indent="yes"
        encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

    <xsl:template match="e:EE">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="e:Sum" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="e:Sum">
        <xsl:variable name="v1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="e:Const[1]"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="v2">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="e:Const[2]"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:variable>
        <Operation>
            <xsl:value-of select="$v1" />
            +
            <xsl:value-of select="$v2" />
        </Operation>
        <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="$v1 + $v2"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works when I `sum` only 2 `Const`. i.e. Sum(8,4)

**However, I want to recursively apply the `Sum template` to every expression in the XML.**

Comment: As I said, I have only implemented Sum operation. However, I want to include `Multiply`,`Substract`, so on. Every operation is an expression, the same as a constant, it means: `8 == Sum(4,4) == Sum(Sum(2,2),4) == Sum(Mult(2,1),6)`. So I must nest the operations in infinite levels (`maxOccurs=unbounded`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using templates effectively - define templates so that they know how to handle the operation at hand.

In the case of Sum, that would be:

1. Get the result value of the first operand (first child element)
2. Get the result value of the second operand (second child element)
3. Add them together.

Sum doesn't need to know what kind of operands it has. It can just apply templates to them and let the XSLT figure that out. This is what we get:

```
<xsl:template match="e:Sum">
  <xsl:variable name="v1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" />
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="v2">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[2]" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select="$v1 + $v2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

It probably makes sense to also define a template for `e:Const`, just so it's clearly defined:

```
<xsl:template match="e:Const">
  <xsl:value-of select ="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Here's a full XSLT, with the addition of `e:Multiply` and a unary operation (`e:Invert`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:e="expr"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output
      method="xml"
      indent="yes"
      encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

  <xsl:template match="e:EE">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="e:Sum">
    <xsl:variable name="v1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="v2">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[2]" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$v1 + $v2"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="e:Multiply">
    <xsl:variable name="v1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="v2">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[2]" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$v1 * $v2"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="e:Invert">
  <xsl:variable name="v1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" />
  </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="1 div $v1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="e:Const">
    <xsl:value-of select ="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on this input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<e:EE xmlns:e="expr"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="xxx/xxx/xxx...">
  <e:Sum>
    <e:Sum>
      <e:Const>8</e:Const>
      <e:Const>4</e:Const>
    </e:Sum>
    <e:Sum>
      <e:Multiply>
        <e:Invert>
          <e:Const>3</e:Const>
        </e:Invert>
        <e:Const>6</e:Const>
      </e:Multiply>
      <e:Const>2</e:Const>
    </e:Sum>
  </e:Sum>
</e:EE>
```

The result is:

```
<e:EE xmlns:e="expr" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">16</e:EE>
```

Comment: This requires that the number of operands be known in advance, does it not?

Comment: @michael.hor257k It would appear from OP's question and their comment on it that the number operands _is_ known in advance. (i.e. `e:Sum` represents the binary operation `a + b`, `e:Multiply` represents the binary operation `a * b`, etc.). From the comment that OP left on their question, it seems that they were satisfied with the sum operation that they had, except that it only worked on `e:Const` operands.

Comment: I didn't get this from OP's question, I only realized it from the acceptance of your answer. That could be my fault, but I still think it needs to be stated expressly.